# Adding Deep Linking to iOS app not working

Tags: ios, deep-linking

I want to add Deep linking to my iOS app. **iOS 14 and Swift 5 !!!**

Done:

1. Added URLs to URL Schemes. For example com.yourdomain
2. Added: https://www.yourdomain.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

   Something like:

   ```
   {
       “applinks”: {
           “apps”: [],
           “details”: [
               {
                   “appID”: “TEAM_ID.BUNDLE_APP_ID”,
                   “paths”: [“*”],
               }
           ]
       }
   }
   ```
3. And add a method to catch event in AppDelegate.swift file.

Does not work and I do not know how I can debug this.

I found that it was some changed and differences between iOS 13 and iOS 14.

Comment: Url schemes and deep links are opposites. Some deep confusion here perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

First, open Xcode, go to Project settings -> capabilities. Scroll down to Associated Domains and turn it on.

Once it is enabled, we shall add any URL that implements our apple-app-site-association resource, preceded by app links. Inside the Domains section, add a applinks:myApp.com. Once this is done, go ahead and try out your app.

https://medium.com/wolox/ios-deep-linking-url-scheme-vs-universal-links-50abd3802f97

Comment: Did it too. Worked with the link that you added. Does not work in iOS 14

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659156

Answer (score -1):

Use branch.io as I know they work on iOS 14